# ios 8.4 simulator is very large size in xcode 6.4?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode6

I just upgraded my xcode from 6.2 to 6.4.Earlier the simulator size of iphone was just fine.But now the size of iphone 5,5s,4s is very large. Now i get scroll bar on both side horizontally & vertically.I don't know why the size is too large.How can resolve this?

Comment: did you check **Window > Scale**

Comment: Yes i missed it. Please answer it.i would accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the menu of your Simulator Check **Window > Scale** and the choose the scale that fits your needs

Alternatively you can use `⌘ + 1` *for 100%* , `⌘ + 2` for 75% or  `⌘ + 3` for 50%

**UPDATE:**

For Xcode 7 it seems that we have more options :)

we can use `⌘ + 4` *for 33%* , `⌘ + 5` *for 25%*

**Xcode 6 and before :**

[image: Simulator Scale]

**Xcode 7 :**

[image: Xcode7]

Answer (score 1):

Now It's more flexible with Xcode 9- Simulator. You can pick & drag any corner or simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot.

[image]